# How can I get the Apache POI Powerpoint code?

Tags: apache-poi

I'm not sure how to actually download the Apache POI scratchpad code that's used for Powerpoint?

The following page says to download the scratchpad jar, but where is that?  I don't see it on the downloads page.

http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy! First, visit the [Apache POI Download Page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html). Next, download the binary distribution, as either Zip or Tar.Gz (depending on what works best on your system). Unpack that, and you'll have all the POI jars and their dependencies. Finally, review the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to check what the dependencies are for each jar.